# Add pre-defined default to column in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I try to test something and I get the issue that I cannot bind the default to the column.

My goal is to alter the column and attach the pre-defined default `True` to that column.

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE default [dbo].[True] as (1)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.aaa ( column_a INT, column_b char(1)) ;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.aaa (column_a)VALUES ( 7 ) ;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.aaa ADD CONSTRAINT DF_col_b DEFAULT [dbo].[True] FOR column_b ;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.aaa (column_a) VALUES ( 10 ) ;
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.aaa ;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.aaa ;
GO
```

In this example I get the error on the ALTER TABLE line

> Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
> The name "dbo.True" is not
>   permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant
>   expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not
>   permitted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Do you get an error? If so: **where** (on what line in your sample code) - and **what exactly** is the error??

Comment: I added the error that your code generated for me to your question, but its better if you do it, in the case I'm for some reason, getting a different error.

Comment: @ConradFrix : you are correct i have the same error. i also tried to use the sp_bindefault but that stored procedure will be removed. so i am searching for an alternative? If there is any of course!

Comment: As written, it looks like `[dbo].[True]` would refer to a table, view, or other system object, and that doesn't make sense as a column default.  Maybe this is something I'm not familiar with, but somehow `[dbo].[True]` needs to resolve to something that fits data type `char(1)` if you want it as a default for column_b.  I'd have expected the default value to be `'t'` or something similar in a case like this, but if you want a boolean then column_b should be a `bit` and its default value should be `1` for true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your column to default to "1", why don't you try this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.aaa ADD CONSTRAINT DF_col_b DEFAULT '1' FOR column_b ;
```

Your default is called True.  If the only possibilities are True or False, then you should probably change the type from char(1) to bit.  And the alter statement would become:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.aaa ADD CONSTRAINT DF_col_b DEFAULT 1 FOR column_b ;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax for binding pre-defined defaults. You need to use [stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177503.aspx):

```
sp_bindefault 'True', 'dbo.aaa.column_b'
```

Comment: @SirCrispalot So is create default.

Comment: yes correct i saw in the documentation that this would be removed. But what is the alternative? if i create a user defined type and want to put a default value there, then it also makes use of the create default?

Comment: User-defined type is either a specification of a base type or a table consisting of columns; you would set default constraints the usual way. But if you want to be able to quickly change default value for a number of columns, CREATE DEFAULT would play nicely. Except for the part that it is scheduled for removal, and we like to do things to last - or at least things that do not force us to return to them every so often ;-)